# PHP Script for Time Based Payment

Tags: php, date, time

I need to write a php script that calculates the total amount a user owes once they have registered. However the registration fees changes depending on the data. So for example:

```
Registration Date | Amount
Before November 15| $200
Before December 15| $250
Before December 30| $300
Before January  15| $350
Before January  30| $400
```

So I can do this using the `time` and `date` functions and making a switch statement but that seems just too easy to calculate such hefty amounts. Am I oversimplifying this or are there other factors to consider?

Also is there already a script written to do such a thing that I could steal? I don't really trust my novice self to write such an important script.

Comment: If you have full dates (with year), you can just take the smallest date that is larger than the registration date.

Comment: What exactly is the question? :S

Comment: @Aziz how to write this script or better yet where to find an already written script that does what I want it

Comment: Testing the script would be the way to go. You probably aren't prepare to go this route, but I suggest you have a look at PHPUnit. You'll write code that checks if a function returns what you expect, depending on the input data. You can select stuff by hand, calculating it in your head. Then see if your code does what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this.

You could:

1. Use MySQL to store the dates when the prices change and query against them.
2. You could use the PHP `date()` function and a simple `elseif` or `switch` statement.
3. You could also use `time()` - the passage of each date offers you a timestamp and you could simple find if the timestamp is larger than each for the different points at which the price changes.

All these methods are possible and fairly simple to implement. Thought might be required as to if this system will be expanded or indeed used in the future.

I'd probably opt for the MySQL approach as you have dynamic control of the dates; add to them, change them, update the prices etc (usually at the whim of management)...

Off the top of my head, something along the lines of:

```
SELECT price 
  from prices 
where
  NOW() >= startdate
  AND NOW() <= enddate
```

prices table (dates in mysql date format):

```
----------------------------------- 
id    price    startdate    enddate
----------------------------------- 
1     200      0            nov15 
2     250      nov16        dec15 
etc...
```